# Error in class file from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am trying to read xml document and the following is what I did in default.aspx

XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Config.xml"));

I need to add in "using System.Xml;" Then it is done.

I wanna change that to class. and I did the same thing, but the following error pops up.

Error   2   The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

And When I right click and resolve, the system give me microsoft.sqlserver which is entirely irrelevant.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't find which 'Server' you are referring to.

Try adding HttpContext.Current before Server.MapPath

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath();
```

It needs

```
using System.Web;
```

And make sure you have a reference to System.Web in your project, or if you don't want one, modify the code to take a string for a path as the parameter, and resolve the path prior to calling the method from somewhere which does have access to HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

It's part of System.Web

Edit: Beaten by lag.